# Is "multiply to" correct?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, mathematics

Can I write "A is multiplied to B"?

The general sentence is "B is multiplied by A", which has the same meaning above.

I could not find any example in the internet, Thanks.

Comment: A is multiplied **by** B.

Comment: A is multiplied to B is an English mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"A multiplied to B" is **incorrect**. When discussing the multiplication of two numbers, we say the first number is multiplied **by** the second number.

Here are the common arithmetic operations:

> `A + B` - B is added **to** A
> `A - B` - B is subtracted **from** A
> `A x B` - A is multiplied **by** B
> `A ÷ B` - A is divided **by** B
> `A / B` - A is divided **by** B (often seen e.g. in computer code,
> spreadsheets, etc)

Comment: It could not be more obvious.

Comment: +1, a side note,: adding the active voice versions  would be a great addition in my opinion.

Comment: @Cardinal - be my guest.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why there are different prepositions used for addition and multiplication because they are both commutative operations, but that is what is idiomatic.

> Add three to five

> Multiply three by five.

Fortunately, you really only need to learn the prepositions for the non-commutative operations of subtraction ("from") and division ("by" or "into").

It is idiomatic (and mathematically sensible) to say

> Add three and five.

> Multiply three and five.

Comment: Could you please directly address my question?  is "A is multiplied to B" correct? if not why, thanks.

Comment: "A is multiplied to B" does not sound right to me. There may not be a logical reason, but we use the preposition "by" for multiplication, or the other idiomatic "and" that the answer mentions.

Comment: @Michael - see answer below.

Comment: The propositions may be different because addition has a very natural physical action of bringing two things together. Multiplication lacks such a natural physical action, so we get more of an operator terminology, as if "B" is doing an action on "A."  Not that this is a logical reason for why we would want two different prepositions, but as we all know, natural languages rarely follow logic.

Comment: It bugs me when Brits say "you times 3 by 2 to get 6"

Comment: @Michael "Multiply to" is not idiomatic. "Multiply by" is idiomatic.

Comment: "Multiplied to" is idiomatic in some contexts *but with a different meaning*.  Cambridge's online dictionary gives thie example: "18 birds multiplied to 100 in just three years." The "to" precedes the final total, not the figure by which the 18 were multiplied.  This is not strictly an arithmetical use of the term "multiply", though, and "A is multiplied to B" sounds very odd - but if someone did say "A is multiplied to B", I might interpret them as meaning as "A is multiplied [by C] to reach a final total of B".